# Transferring liquid from floor back to bottle

Tags: liquids

How to put back liquid into a bottle if the liquid is spilt on a table or floor? The table is too heavy to move it.

Let the liquid be **petrol**.

Comment: Okay, first of all, that is not something I would advice you to do. It's not only impractical, but also very unhygienic. Say, if you spilled something and you want to get it back into a bottle, like if you spilled your shampoo, you might get positive responses. Try editing the question.

Comment: @VarunKN What about giving it to a stray dog or cat?

Comment: I have replaced milk with petrol.

Comment: This may be looking a bit contrived. What problem are you actually trying to solve? I suspect the down-votes are saying *besides a mop or some type of wet-dry vac, what are you actually trying to do?* The bane of sites similar to this have been questions conjuring up contrived challenges with no apparent application or need (see [contrived challenges](http://meta.lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/2431/a-lifehacks-manifesto)). I haven't seen that problem here yet, but changing the problem after it was answered starts to feel like maybe you don't actually have this problem at all. Maybe?

Comment: Sounds a bit contrived, petrol will have evaporated or soaked into flooring by the time a answer would have been found.  Another note is take care about using an electrical vacuum cleaner on flammable liquids.  Very often the working air is used to help cool the motor which is also very often a commutator motor that makes sparks while running.  Other sources of vacuum would be my choice if tricky liquids fell into tricky places regularly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could:

- Use your hand to push it towards a funnel - It's clearly not poured off the table so the table is flat.
- Use a piece of paper/plastic (maybe the lid of a plastic container) to help move the liquid towards a funnel/the bottle
- Use a knife to gently push the liquid accross the surface of the table, towards a funnel/bottle.
- Use paper towels / jay-cloth to absorb the liquid then squeeze them out to get the liquid back
- Use some kind of absorbent powder such as sand/flour to absorb the liquid and then retrieve it via distillation such as heating the material and boiling off the wanted liquid.

Use gloves or other safety equipment as required.

Answer (score 0):

Needed:

- a tube of some kind

Place the bottle lower than the liquid.

Put one end of the tube in the spilled liquid.

Suck on the other end of the tube until the liquid comes out.

put the other end of the tube in the bottle.

As long as the level of fluid in the bottle is lower than the level of the spilled fluid, it will keep flowing.

Sidenote: Afterwards rinse your mouth with soap, petrol is disgusting and unhealthy.